# XML Array Serialization

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I'm using client methods for soap web service.  On one of the methods it has a parameter as string[] list, so i create...

```
string[] myList = { "12345678" };
```

and i send off the request via the client method but i get an error saying SAXException Found character data inside an array element while deserializing.  I know the client method sends this inside the envelope.

```
<List>12345678</List>
```

Which is supposed to be like this...

```
<List><string>12345678</string></List>
```

I've tried the following and still do not get the result which i need.

```
[XmlArrayItem("m")]
public string[] list
{
   get; set;
}
```

i did this to use the class above,

```
string[] a = new string[] { "12345678" };
list = a;
```

and the result is the same,

```
<List>12345678</List>
```

Comment: Can we see some code? what have you tried already? Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815421/why-am-i-getting-org-xml-sax-saxexception-for-this-block-of-xml

Comment: Your actual is result is expected. You are not trying to serialize a list you are trying to serialize multiple strings huge difference. If you want to serialize a collection its possible but requires additional code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126155/c-sharp-array-xml-serialization?rq=1

Comment: Title edited because the question is not related to C#, but to XML Serialization in general.

Comment: Ramhound i followed the link you posted but i still can't get the result.  any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to modify the wsdl in the type it had maxOccurs="Unbounded" type="xsd:string" i changed it to minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:ArrayOfString" and regenerate the client code.  And it worked. Thanks for the suggestions.